# Plots not showing up in plot pane of RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I am using RStudio on a Mac, and I have the following problem: when I want to generate a plot (i.e. plot(cars)), the plot never shows up in the RStudio plot pane. Instead, the plot opens in a separate window (Quartz). I tried to use

```
dev.off()
```

but it did not help. Any idea what I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone faces the same problem: I solved my problem by updating RStudio to the newest version (Version 0.99.902 for Mac).